How can I make the return type of a TypeScript function be a distinct union?
This is a minimalistic example to illustrate the situation. I need my function to deduce its result type from types of the values it returns. Adding an explicit result type annotation for all cases (there are way too many) is not an option.
Consider an example:
function f1() {
   return Math.random() > 0.5 ? { kind: 'a' } as const : { kind: 'b' } as const;
}
f1(); // { kind: 'a' } | { kind: 'b' }

so far it works as expected, but when I add an extra field to one of the cases it turns into (for the lack of a better word) "non-distinct". After some digging I figured it's called "normalized union".
function f2() {
   return Math.random() > 0.5 ? { kind: 'a' } as const : { kind: 'b', x: Math.random() } as const;
}
f2(); // { kind: 'a', x?: undefined } | { kind: 'b', x: number }

I want the result type of f2 to be:
     f2(); // { kind: 'a' } | { kind: 'b', x: number }

In f2 how can I avoid x?: undefined in { kind: 'a', x?: undefined } provided as const is given to { kind : 'a' } via { kind: 'a' } as const?
I am using typescript@next, which is version 5.7.0-dev.20240928 at the time of writing.
SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME:
I found a simple solution in using the identity function:
function fix<const T>(v: T): T { return v; } // <-- identity function
function f2() {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? fix({ kind: 'a' }) : fix({ kind: 'b', x: Math.random() });
}
f2(); // { kind: "a"; } | { kind: "b"; x: number; }


f2 is actually inferred as x?:undefined not x?:number

good catch, fixed

Without explicitly annotating the return type of the function, I think this is a limitation of TS inference.

@ScottZ do you think it's something worth reporting an issue?

There's nothing to report, it's a feature of TS. You might not like it, but it's not a bug. As for how to avoid that, consider making separate constants for them as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz that's really silly of ts to change typing when a local variable created and returned (even immediately)

@AlexanderNenashev You might not like it but it's there for a reason. People complain all the time that you can't index into {x: string} | {y: number} with x or y. But with {x: string, y?: never} | {x?: never, y: number} you can. It's implemented at ms/TS#19513 and explains the reasoning.

found my own answer to duplicate question when researching this. see other q/a for information.

@jcalz wrapping the resulting value into a call to the identity function is suffice

You could use a utility function:
function makeChoice<A, B>(condition: boolean, obj1: A, obj2: B): A | B {
  return condition ? obj1 : obj2;
}

function f2() {
   return makeChoice(Math.random() > 0.5 , { kind: 'a' }, { kind: 'b', x: Math.random() });
}

f2(); 

Playground

yes, it was one of the ways to fix it, and although it works it requires extra code for each case, which i was trying to avoid
